# Variation of Ricci tensor vs Riemann tensor in Gauss-Bonnet density

Tags: general-relativity, variational-calculus, gauss-bonnet

I don't know which steps to follow when perform an infinitesimal variation to the Gauss-Bonnet density with respect to $g^{\mu\nu}$. The first path is to perform variations with respect the Ricci tensor. The Gauss-Bonnet (GB) density is defined as
\begin{align}
\mathcal{G}=R^2-4R_{\mu\nu}R^{\mu\nu}+R_{\alpha\beta\mu\nu}R^{\alpha\beta\mu\nu}.
\end{align}
The variation of the first term is given by
\begin{align}
\delta R^2=2R\delta R=2R\delta\left(g^{\mu\nu}R_{\mu\nu}\right)=2RR_{\mu\nu}\delta g^{\mu\nu}+2g^{\mu\nu}R\delta R_{\mu\nu}.
\end{align}
Here, the variation of the Ricci tensor is given by Palatini's identity $\delta R_{\mu\nu}=\nabla_\rho\delta\Gamma^\rho_{\mu\nu}-\nabla_\nu\delta\Gamma^\lambda_{\lambda\mu}$, then
\begin{align}
\delta R^2&=2RR_{\mu\nu}\delta g^{\mu\nu}+2Rg^{\mu\nu}\left(\nabla_\rho\delta\Gamma^\rho_{\mu\nu}-\nabla_\nu\delta\Gamma^\lambda_{\lambda\mu}\right),
\end{align}
or, after integration by parts
\begin{align}
\delta R^2&=2RR_{\mu\nu}\delta g^{\mu\nu}-2\nabla_\rho R g^{\mu\nu}\delta\Gamma^\rho_{\mu\nu}+2\nabla_\rho\left(Rg^{\mu\nu}\delta\Gamma^\rho_{\mu\nu}\right)+2\nabla_\nu R g^{\mu\nu}\delta\Gamma^\lambda_{\lambda\mu}-2\nabla_\nu\left(R g^{\mu\nu}\delta \Gamma^\lambda_{\lambda\mu}\right).
\end{align}
Recalling the variation of the Christoffel symbol $\delta \Gamma^\rho_{\mu\nu}=\frac{1}{2}g^{\rho\sigma}\left(\nabla_\mu \delta g_{\nu\sigma}+\nabla_\nu \delta g_{\mu\sigma}-\nabla_\sigma \delta g_{\mu\nu}\right)$, we will obtain a certain expression for $\delta R^2$. Please observe I used the variation of $R_{\mu\nu}$ and then $\delta\Gamma^\mu_{\nu\rho}$ in order to obtain terms proportional to $\delta g_{\mu\nu}$. On the other hand, for the same procedure, I could have used variations of the Riemann tensor, as I show next
\begin{align}
\delta R^2=2R\delta R=2R\delta\left(g^{\mu\nu}R_{\mu\nu}\right)=2RR_{\mu\nu}\delta g^{\mu\nu}+2g^{\mu\nu}R\delta \left(g^{\alpha\beta}R_{\alpha\mu\beta\nu}\right)=4RR_{\mu\nu}\delta g^{\mu\nu}+2g^{\mu\nu}g^{\alpha\beta}R\delta R_{\alpha\mu\beta\nu}.
\end{align}
Which path is the truth? To vary the Ricci tensor or the Riemann tensor?